# placing markers at zero locations on cosine wave in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using Jupyter notebook with python 3 and I'm trying to figure out how to plot y = cos(x) over the range -6pi <= x <= 6pi with markers at every point where y=0. I'm looking for a way to code this without having to go through the process of finding all 12 roots. I'm using matplotlib to plot my function. any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about doing it without finding all the roots, but here it is assuming you know the roots

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-6 * np.pi, 6 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.cos(x)

roots = np.arange(-11/2 * np.pi, 13/2 * np.pi, np.pi)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(roots, np.zeros(len(roots)))
plt.show()
```